# How to receive html form post method in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a form

```
<form method="post"  action="http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe">
<input value="tecoc18258@votooe.com">
<button type="submit"> Unsubscribe </button> 
</form>
```

And the API method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{unsubscribe}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Unsubscribe([FromForm] string email)
{
    var newsLetterSubscription = await Mediator.Send(new UnsubscribeCommand(Email: email));

    return Ok(newsLetterSubscription);
}
```

When clicking the the Unsubscribe button, API method is hit, but the value of `email` is `NULL`.

I need that email parameter also.

How can I send the post request from html form and how to receive?

HTTP request should like this

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe' \
--form 'email="hekoke1094@wodeda.com"'
```

Edit:
my code for form

```
  mm.Body = $"<p>Your Secret Password is { password }</b> To unsubscribe your account, <form method =\"POST\"action=\"http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe\" class=\"inline\"> <input name=\"email\" value=\"{toEmail}\"> <button > Unsubscribe </button> </form>.</p>";
```

the above form is sent to a email, when I inspect the form in that email, the `name = "email"`  part is missing.
this is the mistake.

anyone knows the mistake?

Comment: use `[FromBody] string email` for your Unsubscribe method, to read the request body.

Comment: The form you provided and the `Http reuqest` do not match, Are you sure you can hit the endpoint by sending the form without `<input name="email".../>`

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Hi, I got `415 "Unsupported Media Type"`  when using ` [FromBody] string email `

Comment: @XinranShen I have edited my question. Even I send <input name="email".../> with this, still email is null when hitting the end point

Comment: @hanushi when you use `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe' \
--form 'email="hekoke1094@wodeda.com"'`, can api reveive the data successfully?

Comment: @XinranShen yes, I found the mistake, when i inspect the form `name = "email"`  is missing. I have edited my question, Do you know the mistakes in my code, I send `  <input name=\"email\" value=\"{toEmail}\"> ` too

Comment: @hanushi I tried the form with `<input value="tecoc18258@votooe.com" name="Email">` THE API can receive value successfully. So I  doubt about Whether the form can be successfully rendered on the front-end page By `mm.Body = $"<p>Your Secret Password is { password }</b> To unsubscribe your account, <form method =\"POST\"action=\"http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe\" class=\"inline\"> <input name=\"email\" value=\"{toEmail}\"> <button > Unsubscribe </button> </form>.</p>";`

Comment: @hanushi I do not think that you need to use `FromForm` or `FormBody` in your case, just trying submitting the form with the parameter: `public async Task<IActionResult> Unsubscribe(string email)`